# Accepting port on linux/Can only access port using local, timeout on ip

Tags: ubuntu, networking, port-forwarding

I have opened the port `25565` on my rounter (aka the minecraft server port).
I am already hosting a website on this server:

```
togtja@togtja_server:/$ sudo iptables -nL | grep 80
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443 /* 'dapp_Apache%20Full' */
```

And when running the server, I double check that the port is being listen to:

```
/**Some other ports as well such as 22 from ssh**/
apache2   1926            root    4u  IPv6  29136      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2   1926            root    6u  IPv6  29140      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
apache2   1927        www-data    4u  IPv6  29136      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2   1927        www-data    6u  IPv6  29140      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
apache2   1928        www-data    4u  IPv6  29136      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2   1928        www-data    6u  IPv6  29140      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
java      3159       togtja      52u  IPv6  41266      0t0  TCP *:25565 (LISTEN)
```

However when I run `telnet` or `nc` on the port:

```
togtja@togtja_server:/$ nc -z -v -w5 my_ip 25565
nc: connect to my_ip port 25565 (tcp) timed out: Operation now in progress
```

If I try other port that is supposed to be close, I get directly refused

```
togtja@togtja_server:/$ nc -z -v -w5 my_ip 1337
nc: connect to my_ip port 1337 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

However, I get through if I try localhost

```
togtja@togtja_server:/$ nc -z -v -w5 localhost 25565
Connection to localhost 25565 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
```

and it refuses unopened port on local, as expected:

```
togtja@togtja_server:/$ nc -z -v -w5 localhost 1337
nc: connect to localhost port 1337 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

I belive I *might* have locked all ports up when I was setting up my web server, except those with explicit accept, but don't know where those setting would be, or if that is the issues at all.
Note: I am running a ubuntu 18.04 server (with no GUI).

**EDIT:**
To clarify, I am also running the `nc my_ip` commands from a pc on a different network, to verifying it not only working from the local server

Comment: The `lsof` output you are showing lists IPv6 entries only. Does `my_ip` resolve to an IPv6 address? And, if not, is your process also listening over IPv4?

Comment: @fra-san No my_ip is a IPv4 address, and it seems like it's only listening in IPv6, now that you mention it. running  `netstat -t --listening` gives me the port on `tcp6`. That being said however, my web ports `80/443` are also only on IPv6

Comment: My wild guess about your web server is that something (your router?) in front of your server implements an IP translation layer. You seem to be making your tests from the server itself, so we don't know whether connecting to an arbitrary IPv6 service on `my_ip` over IPv4 from an outside network would work (though, apparently, the web server works). Does `nc -z -w -4 my_ip 80` (or `nc -z -w -4 localhost 80`) succeed?

Comment: Ohh I am running it both on from the server and from my own machine on a different network. I am ssh'ing into my machine. The `nc -z -w5 -4 my_ip` on a machine on a different network succedes, and trying `nc -z -w5 -4 -v localhost 25565`on my server succedes. Looking into my rounter, it does not have a WAN6/ipv6 adress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I somehow managed to set the default Pollicy for IP tables to `DROP`.
so when calling `sudo iptables -L`, I got:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

so I added an exception for my port running:
`sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 25565 -j ACCEPT`
`INPUT`, could be `FORWARD` or `OUTPUT` depedning on what you want to make a rule expcetion for.

To change an entire table chain to one polocy you can do:
`sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT`, this would make the default policy for INPUT to be accept